# minifiedEnabled leads to renderscript crash >Kitkat

Tags: android, proguard, android-support-library, renderscript

Recent versions of the renderscriptSupport fixed renderscript back to version 11. I tested these, on proper devices and emulators. But, after production everybody running KitKat or lower crashed.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.photoembroidery.tat.olsennoise"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 9
    versionName "1.6bRS"

    renderscriptTargetApi 23
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}
```

The built script it had was:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Which enabled minify for the releases, and any signed APK crashed. Whereas when I changed to:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

The signed APKs stopped crashing on Kitkat devices.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.photoembroidery.tat.olsennoise/com.photoembroidery.tat.olsennoise.OlsenNoise}: android.support.v8.renderscript.m: Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNI_ERR returned from JNI_OnLoad in "/data/app/com.photoembroidery.tat.olsennoise-1/lib/arm/librsjni.so" Support lib API: 2301
Caused by: android.support.v8.renderscript.m: Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNI_ERR returned from JNI_OnLoad in "/data/app/com.photoembroidery.tat.olsennoise-1/lib/arm/librsjni.so" Support lib API: 2301
```

and:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static or non-static method "Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript;.nDeviceDestroy(J)V"
```

Is there something else I might be missing? It is the minified right? Is there someway to safely get most of minified working for most of the script (extra meg of bloat isn't awesome)?

Comment: What if you set the renderscriptTargetApi to 11? You should always make it equal to the minimum target api

Comment: I'll do that, because yeah. But, it still crashes. The minified version crashes, the non-minified version does not. With it set to 11.

Comment: The same exact error UnsatisfiedLinkError was reported in my app crash log Android on 5.0 and 6.0 as well - minSdkVersion 17, renderscriptTargetApi 17. You are correct, only the minified version crashes. I just ended up removing renderscript from my project entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem persists Dec 2016 but proguard rules work:

```
-keep class com.photoembroidery.tat.olsennoise.** {*;}
-keep class android.support.v8.renderscript.** {*;}
```

Stopped crashing on KitKat.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

Using AndroidX you need

```
-keep class androidx.renderscript.** { *; }
```